# Find rows with no match

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compare and identify all IDs that have a mismatch in the codes between the categories, upper and lower case are only examples and I cannot base the join on the category field as they are different.

e.g: ID 1 - cat A, a have the same code but ID 3, cat E and e have a mismatch, same with ID#4.

Edit: sorry - after posting the question, and looking at the answers I have realized that my question was not conveying what I am looking for, and I have mocked up data incorrectly. The Category doesn't always have the same name as uppercase/lowercase letters, this was only meant to be an example.

```
T1    
ID   Cat   Code    
1     A     100    
1     a     100    
1     B     101    
1     b     101    
2     C     102    
2     D     103    
2     d     103    
3     E     104    
3     e     107    
3     F     105    
3     g     106    
4     I     109
4     i     110
5     ABC   111
5     XYZ   112
5     KLM   123
6     PQR   113
6     STU   113
```

Desired output:

```
ID    Cat   Code    
3     E     104        
3     e     107     
4     I     109    
4     i     110   
5     ABC   111
5     XYZ   112
5     KLM   123
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  You need to show a bit of effort if you want someone to help you.

Comment: ofcourse I did, since I was not able to figure out a solution, I posted a quesiton. not very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

Use `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where exists (select 1
              from t1 tt1
              where tt1.id = t1.id and
                    upper(tt1.cat) = upper(t1.cat) and
                    tt1.cat <> t1.cat and
                    tt1.code <> t1.code
             );
```

Oracle is case-sensitive by default.

Comment: how do I identify the mismatch if the categories are not A vs a, sometimes they can be different. I do not want to base my join on the category field to identify the mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join like below to handle this issue:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
inner join tablename t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID and upper(t1.Cat) = upper(t2.Cat)
where t1.Code <> t2.Code
```

Comment: how do I identify the mismatch if the categories are not A vs a, sometimes they can be different. I do not want to base my join on the category field to identify the mismatch

Comment: @Skn can you add some example data for the case you mentioned?

Comment: I have added some additional data.

Comment: @Skn why "5     ABC   111" is not in your output list? How did u decide it?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: @Skn Then in this case why "3     F     105  " is not in your output list? I think you should focus on providing a more consistent and understandable example data.